# In springer nature template (sn-jnl), cross-reference of label in `enumerate' does not work well

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, springernature

When I nest the `enumerate` environment, it seems that the reference of lower levels are generated multiply. How should I fix it without modifying the template itself?

Minimal example

```
\documentclass[sn-aps,pdflatex]{sn-jnl}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{itm:1}
    \item \label{itm:2}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{itm:2a}
        \item \label{itm:2b}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \label{itm:2b1}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\ref{itm:1}, \ref{itm:2}, \ref{itm:2a}, \ref{itm:2b}, \ref{itm:2b1}.
\end{document}
```

Expected output of references: `1, 2, 2a, 2b, 2b.i`

Actual output of references: `1, 2, 22a, 22b, 2(2b)2b.i.`

I guess I should change `\theenumii` and `\theenumiii` by

```
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\alph{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{\roman{enumiii}}
```

However, in this case, the output of references are: `1, 2, 2a, 2b, 2(b)i.`

It seems that, there should still have something that influents the output of the references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class has

```
\def\labelenumi{\theenumi.}         \def\theenumi{\arabic{enumi}}
\def\labelenumii{(\alph{enumii})}   \def\theenumii{\theenumi\alph{enumii}}
\def\labelenumiii{(\roman{enumiii})}\def\theenumiii{\theenumii.\roman{enumiii}}
\def\labelenumiv{(\Alph{enumiv})}   \def\theenumiv{\theenumiii.\Alph{enumiv}}
```

which doesn't seem a problem and, in the intentions of the class developers you *should* get `2a` with `\ref{itm:2a}`. But in the `.aux` file we see

```
\newlabel{itm:2a}{{22a}{1}{}{Item.3}{}}
```

What happens? The developers of the class forgot about `\p@<counter>`.

```
\documentclass[sn-aps,pdflatex]{sn-jnl}

\labelformat{enumi}{#1}
\labelformat{enumii}{#1}
\labelformat{enumiii}{#1}
\labelformat{enumiv}{#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{itm:1}
    \item \label{itm:2}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{itm:2a}
        \item \label{itm:2b}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \label{itm:2b1}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\ref{itm:1}, \ref{itm:2}, \ref{itm:2a}, \ref{itm:2b}, \ref{itm:2b1}.
\end{document}
```

[image]